# How to show inferred TypeScript type in WebStorm?

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, webstorm, type-inference

In VS2012, you can hover over a typescript variable and it will show you the inferred type. Is there a similar feature in webstorm?

Comment: **Ctrl+Q** (View | Quick Documentation) ?

Comment: @LazyOne, **Ctrl+Q** does nothing on Mac WebStorm

Comment: @Green The menu item where you can check what shortcut is has assigned is written in the braces/brakets. OP uses Windows where that `Ctrl+Q` shortcut works. On Mac it might be just `F1` or some another

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Although not perfect. Press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key (or <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> on macOS) and hover over a variable with the mouse to kick in the inference logic in webstorm :

[image]

Comment: I'm using Webstorm 2016.1 with default configs, but I'm not seeing that. Did you have to do anything special?

Comment: Works well on Mac WebStorm 2019.1.2. 
Press and hold **Cmd** and hover a variable.

Comment: Cmd+hover works fine but i would like to connect this to a keyboard short cut. Is there a way?

Comment: if you have a large object being returned, it only shows a summary "...12 more...". Is there a way to access the entire type?

Answer (score 51):

Assuming the cursor is already on the variable the best way is:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. <kbd>Return</kbd>

Starting from **WS2017.2** <kbd>Ctrl (Cmd)</kbd> + <kbd>Hover</kbd> shows inferred type.

Also you can try **Quick Documentation**:
 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>   ( <kbd>F1</kbd> for OS X )

Updated: in 2020.1 it will work as a part of the quick documentation and it works on hover if *Preferences > EditoGeneral > Show quick documentation on mouse move* is checked

Comment: I'm getting a type:<unknown> and not a type:any like I should. Did you have that issue?

Comment: For people who have changed the default key bindings, search for `Expression Type` in the keymap settings

Comment: ^^^ This was the one answer that worked for me. Hook a shortcut up to `Expression Type`.

Comment: Cmd+hover works fine but I would like to connect this to a keyboard shortcut. Is there a way?

Answer (score 9):

Late to the party, and not sure when this came out, but there is a setting:

`Show quick documentation on mouse move. Delay: [500] ms`

Where delay is editable.

You can get to it by

`File -> Settings -> Editor/General -> #Other / Show quick documentation on mouse move`

Works similar to VS

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the context, there are different ways to get type information. (Shortcuts for OS X)

1. *View > Expression Type* <kbd>⌘⇧P</kbd>: shows a popup
2. *Navigate > Type Declaration* <kbd>⌘⇧B</kbd>: navigates in the editor
3. If 2. does not help, I do *Navigate > Declaration* <kbd>⌘B</kbd> and then 2.
4. *View > Quick Definition* <kbd>⌥Space</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘Y</kbd>)
5. *View > Parameter Info* <kbd>⌘P</kbd>: shows a popup with the declaration of a function parameter

Answer (score 6):

As an addition to hovering to see the type, since version 2020.3 you can go to
`Settings -> Editor -> Inlay Hints -> TypeScript -> Type annotations`
and check all the boxes, to see the type interference right away in your IDE:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Besides the CTRL/CMD and hovering you also need to have your dependencies (with ts in them) installed and node interpreter selected in the Langauge & Frameworks > TypeScript settings