# How to find out the type of a TypeScript element (variable, function) in WebStorm?

Tags: typescript, webstorm

Is there a way in WebStorm to get the type of a function or a variable?

In Visual Studio Code, I can hover over an identifier, and I get type information about the element under the cursor:

[image: Hover in VSCode]

It can also show the effective type of a variable:

[image: Hover in VSCode]

Both are extremely helpful tools for better understanding the code.

Is there a way in WebStorm to access the effective type of an element in the editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+I</kbd> (`View/Quick Definition`)
- Try <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> (`View/Expression Type`) - it normally shows the inferred variable type

Since WS2017.2 <kbd>Ctrl+Hover</kbd> shows inferred type.

Comment: Unfortunately, this works only in the simplest cases. It does not work if I have something like ```function foo() {
    return {x:1, y:false}
}

class Foo {
    bar() {
        return foo();
    }
}
``` and I click on the `bar` method in the class `Foo`.

Comment: There is a better answer over https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840018/how-to-show-inferred-typescript-type-in-webstorm basically hold Ctrl when you mouse over.