# How to explore TypeScript inferred types in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript, webstorm

Is there an option in WebStorm that I can use to explore or navigate the inferred (or just any) TypeScript definitions and types considering the following:

The <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+I</kbd> (`View/Quick Definition`) is a good option, but not interactive. For example, the <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> (`Quick Documentation`) for JSDoc is interactive, when this menu opens it is possible to easily navigate (using JSDoc hyperlinks) from type to type. But with <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+I</kbd> option I can only see `one` definition at a time, and if this type is an `interface` or other complex type combined from multiple types, I can't explore it, so in the best case I need to look for it with `Find a Symbol` option or by other means.

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> (`View/Expression Type`) - this shows the inferred type (when it works), but this is not enough due to the same reason, I can't even click on it (with <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> for example) because it is not interactive either. So in the best case, I need to remember the inferred type name (returned by this option), I can't even copy it, and then in the best case I can find it with `Find a Symbol` option or by other means.

So I am looking for an option, if exist, which combines the `Quick Definition` & `Expression Type` menus in one place? As I said, like the JSDoc `Quick View` hyperlinks menu.

I will try to find time and add some screen shots to explain the problem and expected solution in a better way.

---

Considering answers for the following questions, I am asking for a way to deeply explore the inferred type, not only show it's name or info:

- [How to show inferred TypeScript type in WebStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840018/how-to-show-inferred-typescript-type-in-webstorm)
- [How to find out the type of a TypeScript element (variable, function) in WebStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36940762/how-to-find-out-the-type-of-a-typescript-element-variable-function-in-webstor)

Comment: Possible feature request https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19686 ?

Comment: Is `Navigate/Declaration` what you're looking for?

Comment: I am looking for `Navigate/Declaration` BUT inside the context menus of `View/Quick Definition` and `View/Expression Type`. I think there is no such a feature, thus there is a request for it on the intellij youtrack site

Answer (score 0):

At least for a variable, I was able to do this:

<kbd>Option</kbd> → `Specify Type Explicitly`. The TypeScript type was then pasted next to it. I could then copy and explore the type.

[image]

[image]

However, the order of keys aren't preserved unfortunately.